# Can't remove OWNER access to a Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a server that writes some data files to a Cloud Storage bucket, using a service account to which I have granted "Storage Object Creator" permissions for the bucket. I want that service account's permissions to be write-only.

The Storage Object Creator permission also allows read access, as far as I can tell, so I wanted to just remove the permission for the objects after they have been written.  I thought I could use an ACL to do this, but it doesn't seem to work.  If I use

`gsutil acl get gs://bucket/object > acl.json`

Then edit acl.json to remove the **owner** permission for the service account, then use

`gsutil acl set acl.json gs://bucket/object`

to update the ACL, I find that nothing has changed; the OWNER permission is still there if I check the ACL again.  The same thing happens if I try to remove the OWNER permission in the Cloud Console web interface.

Is there a way to remove that permission?  Or another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the `OWNER` permissions for the service account that uploaded the object, from:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#bestpractices

> The bucket or object owner always has `OWNER` permission of the bucket or object.
>
> The owner of a bucket is the project owners group, and the owner of an object is either the user who uploaded the object, or the project owners group if the object was uploaded by an anonymous user.
>
> When you apply a new ACL to a bucket or object, Cloud Storage respectively adds `OWNER` permission to the bucket or object owner if you omit the grants.

I have not tried this, but you could upload the objects using once service account (call it SA1), then rewrite the objects using a separate service account (call it SA2), and then delete the objects.  SA1 will no longer be the owner, and therefore won't have read permissions.  SA2 will continue to have both read and write permissions though, there is no way to prevent the owner of an object from reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the object does the trick.

```
gsutil mv -p gs://bucket/object gs://bucket/object-renamed
gsutil mv -p gs://bucket/object-renamed gs://bucket/object
```

The *renamer* service account will become the object `OWNER`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to give a principal upload access to a object storage but not list / download permission
You need to:

1. Switch to Uniform bucket Level access on the bucket so that ownership isn't assigned to the uploader since that gives list and download permissions no matter what role is assigned to the principal.
2. Use something else than gsutil and gcloud.
   [as none of googles cli tool allow uploads to a bucket without the object.list and object.get permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects)

You can either write your own tool using the SDK or use a tool like [rclone](https://rclone.org/)
with the flags:

```
--gcs-bucket-policy-only
--gcs-no-check-bucket
--no-check-dest
```