# Preventing Google Cloud Storage account owner visibility into user bucket objects

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am creating an application that will store user data in Google Storage buckets. To start, I want to create one bucket for each user.

As the application / account owner, I expect to be able to see that a user’s bucket exists, but I don’t want to have access to the contents of that bucket.

Does Google Cloud Storage offer this option? I expect it depends on IAM settings, but I’m unsure about the best approach, or best practice.

Comment: The **owner** role is legacy but can basically do anything in a project including granting itself additional permissions (IAM Roles).

Comment: Interesting — it seems that I should either create a new project without the "owner" role, or find away to remove these permissions? And then I would guess that I would not have access to user buckets, since I could define more specific controls for what I have access to.

Comment: Hi @charliesneath, have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017679/cant-remove-owner-access-to-a-google-cloud-storage-object). This might help.

Comment: @CatherineO: Yes, but that seems like a work-around for something that I’m hoping is more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Custom Role and attach it to the service account and/or user account that you are using.

On that Custom Role you can add only the required bucket permission: storage.buckets.list

Is a very good security practice to apply the least privilege principle for Service Accounts and User Accounts. Custom roles help us with it.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) we have a list with every privilege available. You can create Custom Roles with the required privileges only.

[UPDATE]

Every project needs at least one admin (project-owner) and this guy will have superpowers. Cause, tomorrow you may need to change permissions: For instance: list buckets and list objects but not see objects. Without admin permissions, you will not be able to do it.

So, to prevent even someone with the role project-owner from being able to see the contents of the bucket, it is possible to encrypt the objects. That way, only those who have the encryption key can consume the contents of the bucket. See more about encryption [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/encryption/customer-supplied-encryption-keys)

See ya

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address the primary question of how to ensure that the account owner does NOT have access to buckets with user data.

Comment: See this link: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#role_types
Users have roles, and roles have permissions.
On Google Cloud we have 3 types of roles: Basic, Pre-Defined, and Custom
Owner is a type of Basic Role.

My suggestion is: Don't use Basic Roles.
Create a Custom Role with the required permissions only

How to create a custom role?
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles

Comment: Got it, thanks for that detail. The challenge is that when trying to update my role with specific permissions, I get the error “_The project must have at least one principal with the owner role_.” Still trying to figure out how I can be own owner without access to buckets with user data.

Comment: You can't.

Every project needs at least one admin (owner) and this guy will have superpowers

Cause, tomorrow you may need to change permissions:

For instance:
list buckets and list objects but not see objects

Without admin permissions, you will not be able to do it.

Another option is to encrypt the data using customer-supplied keys. The owner will continue to be able to see the objects, but encrypted keys.

See more about Customer-Supplied Keys here:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/encryption/customer-supplied-encryption-keys

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. It seems that the IAM policy for user data buckets should grant read access to only the user, but grant list/delete access to the project owner (e.g. me). More research helped me understand a default IAM policy is automatically being applied to new buckets, and custom roles (as you mentioned above) will help achieve what I want.

Comment: Great @charliesneath
I've updated the answer with the complements